# Curves whose stable reductions do not contain rational curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over $K:=K(A)$. $A$ is a strict henselian ring, $A/m=k=\bar k$. Suppose $\cal X$ is a stable model of $X$, ${\cal X}_{s}$ is the special fiber.

My question is:

what are the conditions on $X$ so that $\cal X_{s}$ does not contain any rational curves?

Comment: Kiseki, could you specify a bit more what you are looking for?  For instance, are you looking for conditions expressed in terms of the monodromy action of the Galois group of $K$ on the first $l$-adic cohomology group of $X$?

Comment: By the adjunction formula, a rational curve $E$ on $\mathcal X$ will have self-intersection $-E^2 = -2 - K\cdot E$, where $K$ is a canonical divisor of $\mathcal X /O_K$. So a necessary and sufficient condition to have no rational curves is that there aren't any vertical divisors $E$  such that $E^2 = -2 - (K,E)$.